# C++ memory cleanup on mac

Tags: c++, macos, memory, memory-management

I have C++ code on a Mac that looks something like this:

```
Object* objectArray = new Object[1000];
// do some stuff...
delete[] objectArray;
```

Now it compiles great, and runs great

However, when I look at the Activity Monitor for the process, I find that I allocate 250MB that then do not become available again even after I execute the `delete[]` statement. Is there a way to make that memory available again without quitting the C++ application?

Comment: Let the OS care about that. It will almost certainly reuse that memory or release it at a more appropriate time.

Comment: The Activity Monitor doesn’t accurately report memory usage, for the reasons laid out below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Echoing @sftrabbit and @pmr: When you allocate a block of memory, the OS gives you at least that much memory marked as "active." You'll see this term in Activity Monitor under System Memory. Then when you're done with it, you mark at least some of it as "inactive" which means that the OS is free to come along and take it from you if it needs to. Actually reclaiming it is somewhat expensive, and the system assumes that if you asked for the memory once, you'll probably want it again, so unless there is memory pressure it's not going to bother you for it. When the OS does reclaim it, it'll mark it as "free" unless it is immediately needed for some other process.

While not necessarily related to your C++ code, in your ObjC code you'll find that deallocated memory may not even show up on the "inactive" pool. Cocoa (really CoreFoundation) maintains pools of allocated memory blocks that it can dole back out quickly. This avoids the large overhead of `malloc()`. Not specifically relevant to your question, but noteworthy in Mac apps generally.

While I generally agree that it is not a huge issue, I wouldn't be completely cavalier about it. Allocating and freeing large blocks of memory is still expensive and can force the system into a memory pressure situation where it has to actually go bug other processes for their memory, thus degrading overall system performance (and then making it more expensive for other apps when they need to allocate memory later). If you can avoid it, it's worth trying to keep your high-water mark (the largest memory you ever request) from spiking unnecessarily.

But if you really need this memory, it's not a problem. Memory is there to be used.

Answer (score 5):

Just because the memory isn't made available again instantly doesn't mean the operating system isn't going to take it from your process when another process requests more memory. What you are seeing is happening in a lot of programs and keeps confusing users over and over, but it usually not worth your time. If there is no leak you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

A call to `new` allocates memory for an object. If there is not enough memory in the free store to satisfy the request, the library asks the OS for more memory. A call to `delete` does not necessarily return that memory to the OS. On the assumption that a program will use more memory from the free store later, the library generally hangs on to that memory. So tools at the OS level won't show that the memory has been freed, because those tools don't look at the internal structure of the application's free store. All they see is that the OS gave some memory to the application and hasn't gotten it back yet.